# error found when loading /home/user/.profile

Tags: linux

Hola vengo con un problema debido a que al iniciar mi pc en Linux Mint 21 Cinnamon edition me sale estto al entrar error found when loading /home/benjamin/.profile: /home/benjamin/.profile linea 1: export:  '/home/benjamin/.profile:': no es un identificador valido /home/benjamin/.profile: linea 1: export 'shells.': no es un identificador valido lla vdd no entiendo nada de linux espero que alguien me ayude yy gracias

Comment: ¿Modificaste manualmente el archivo `.profile`? Ve a tu home, y abre el archivo `.profile` con tu editor de texto favorito (puedes usar vscode). Revisa el contenido del archivo y colócalo acá en SO, así podremos ayudarte mejor. Por el mensaje de error se puede apreciar que el problema está la primera línea: `export 'shells.'` lo cuál no es válido y por eso tu mensaje. Por ahora prueba eliminando esa primera línea y comprueba si el error desaparece.

Comment: Hola amigo no entiendo mucho de linux pero cuando entro a la arpeta mia osea benjamin no veo ningun archivo llamado .profile solo vi estos archivos 
/home/benjamin/Público /home/benjamin/virtual-drives
/home/benjamin/config.json /home/benjamin/ControlScheme.json
/home/benjamin/externalactives /home/benjamin/hs_err_pid13586.log
/home/benjamin/imgui.ini /home/benjamin/settings
/home/benjamin/stats

Comment: Eso es porque en linux todos los archivos cuyo nombre comience por punto están ocultos por defecto. Prueba seleccionar en el menún de tu explorador Ver > Mostrar los archivos y carpetas ocultos. Puedes verlo tambien en una terminal usando `ls -a` y abrir el archivo usando `code .profile`

Comment: [Edita](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/574408/edit) tu pregunta y agrega el código ahí. El código no se agrega en comentarios.

Comment: @JaimeMenendez amigo si tenes discord o cualquier cosa para comunicarnos mejor pasamelo pq no entiendo nada cuando edito me dice que el codigo necesita espacios no se que

Comment: Ejecuta `cat /home/benjamin/.profile` y agréganos el resultado a la pregunta original.